# Will QLocalServer/QLocalSocket guarantee message delivering?

Tags: qt

Will message sent by QLocalSocket be corrupted during transfer?
In short, will it act like UDPSocket and requires a complex parser on the receiving side?

Comment: I can't give a definitive answer, but since it's regularly used for IPC and inter-thread communication, I don't see why this would be an issue.

Comment: Sorry, so you mean it won't be corruptted?

Comment: Correct. I'd wait for someone to confirm, but since it's a go-to solution for IPC, packet corruption should not be an issue.